# Magento CSV Import Errors Type Not Defined

Tags: csv, magento

I am trying to import products to Magento via a csv and i keep getting this error.
[image]

Here is my setup in excel
[image]

And lastly here is my mapping
[image]

Any suggestions i cant seem to find an answer anywhere!

Comment: where is `type` in your csv file?

Comment: Its in column A http://i.imgur.com/L6AN7.jpg

Comment: Magento is treating your CSV headers line (line1) like a product import line... and fails normally.. You must have a malformed CSV file. Compare your file with an exported one (from Dataflow / Export All product profile)

Comment: I finally got it to import but it says it did 32 records but only added 22 products to the database

Comment: Maybe somes lines just do an update of an existing product (values for a different store)

Comment: Also make sure that php timeout settings are adequate to process the entire import. If the timeout values are too low, the import won't complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And also make sure that your CSV file is saved with UTF-8 encoded.